# Raspberry PI, PCF8574AT, MPU6050, BMP180 i2c voltage difference?

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, lcd, level-shifting, imu

I'm building a rpi 3 b+ based robot which collects data from a MPU6050 (Gy-521 breakout board, I power it with 5V), a BMP180 (3V input) and displays some data on a LCD via a PCF8574AT i2c converter (which I want to power with 5V, because on 3V the LCD loses contrast). Currently it is utilizing an Arduino connected with a usb cable to collect the data and print to the LCD (so all the devices are connected to the Arduino, not the rpi, but I want to get rid of the Arduino completely and control everything from the rpi directly). The problem is that rpi supports max 3V on the GPIO. Information about these modules' i2c voltage are hard to find, although I read in the datasheet of the PCF8574AT converter that it has a 'non-overvoltage i/o' - but i'm still unsure if it really means that it can be safely connected to the rpi? And won't the mpu6050 and bmp180 also fry the rpi? Will I need a voltage level converter or are these devices compatible with the rpi's 3V GPIO i2c?
Links to docs: pcf8574at: https://abc-rc.pl/templates/images/files/995/1426613116-konwertertwi.pdf
Mpu6050: https://abc-rc.pl/templates/images/files/995/1443347244-dokumentacja.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I2c is an open collector bus. You could easily power the bus at 3.3V of the RPi, and it will be safe. But then the devices won't work. They expect a Voltage Input High of 0.7*VDD which is 0.7 * 5v  = 3.5V. No guarante that they will read the input from the RPi via the pull up resistor.

You will need an i2c voltage converter. Please search the site as there are hundred of questions explaining these circuits.

Comment: Ok, but as the BMP180 runs at 3.3V, if I connect all the i2c wires together (all SDA to one and all scl to one), and then connect these to the converter on the HV (5V) side, won't this fry the bmp running on 3V, as it converts from 5V?

Comment: You put it on the 3.3V side.

Comment: Alright, and how about the mpu6050 and PCF8574AT? Which goes to 3V and which to 5V?

Comment: Alright, i got this working